# Regex with a few lines containing "#" and a specific text

Tags: string, perl

We are trying to update the multiple servers configuration file, with new entries in specific location, before a specific lines. The example contains part of the configuration file

```
#
#
#
#
# The lines below should not be replaced in this file
# Contact Sysadmins before make changes to this line
```

I need to match these lines including the "#" and newline, with the above lines and then add new entry above these line, as an example

```
New entry 1
New entry 2
#
#
#
#
# The lines below should not be replaced in this file
# Contact Sysadmins before make changes to this line
```

Tried this in perl as an inline code, as follows

```
/usr/bin/perl -lne 'print "\nNew entry 1\nNew entry 2" if (/[#\n]*# The lines below should not be replaced in this file/); print $_' filename
```

My regex does not work. I am not an expert in perl or regex in any other language. On many of the server instead of  4 "#" there may be 2 or 3, before the line. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I have to update the same file on 2000+ servers.

Comment: Welcome to SO. In your `if` clause is an regex. If this matches, the block will be executed. There is no change on your data. Then an `if` needs in pearl always a block `{}`!

Comment: @Andy A. No, `EXPR if COND_EXPR;` is a perfectly valid Perl statement. It's basically the same as `if (COND_EXPR) { EXPR; }`.

Comment: @ikegami. Oh, you are right, of course!!

Answer (score 2):

You are processing the file one line at a time, so `[#\n]*#` won't ever match anything but `#`.

One solution involves telling Perl to treat the entire file as one line and thus reading the entire file into memory.

```sh
perl -0777pe's/^([#\n]*# The lines below)/New entry 1\nNew entry 2\n$1/mg'
```

The other would involve postponing the print of lines starting with `#`.

```sh
perl -ne'
   $buf .= $_;
   next if /^#$/;
   print "New entry 1\nNew entry 2\n" if /^# The lines below/;
   print $buf;
   $buf = "";
   END { print $buf; }
'
```

---

Tested:

```
$ perl -0777pe's/^([#\n]*# The lines below)/New entry 1\nNew entry 2\n$1/mg' file
New entry 1
New entry 2
#
#
#
#
# The lines below should not be replaced in this file
# Contact Sysadmins before make changes to this line

$ perl -ne'
   $buf .= $_;
   next if /^#$/;
   print "New entry 1\nNew entry 2\n" if /^# The lines below/;
   print $buf;
   $buf = "";
   END { print $buf; }
' file
New entry 1
New entry 2
#
#
#
#
# The lines below should not be replaced in this file
# Contact Sysadmins before make changes to this line
```

(Other tests perform too.)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but neither of the suggested perl inlines work exactly as per what I need. The 1st one gives an output very similar to what I need, like
#
#
#
New entry 1
New entry 2
# The lines below should not be replaced in this file

Comment: There was an error in the first which I fixed, but the second did exactly what the question *asked*. (And now, so does the first). If that's not what you *need*, fix your question and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You can use sed command to substitute the new entry lines before the #lines start poistion.

sed '/#/ s/^/New Entry 1\n/' input.txt